# NSWindow with childwindows flickering

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a main NSWindow with 3 child NSWindows like:

```
_______________________________________
|     ||                      ||      |
|     ||                      ||      |
|     ||                      ||      |
|     ||                      ||      |
|     ||                      ||      |
|     ||                      ||      |
|_____||______________________||______|
```

I have already been able to to the resizing of the left and right child windows with the click of a button, with almost the same effect as the Xcode side bars, but when I add content to the child windows (as, for instance, a NSTableView) if I close one of the side bars I get a Flickering and a delayed effect on any resize I perform after it is closed. Even the normal resizing of the main Window. Any ideas why this could be happening?

code 1: the remove action of the sidebar.

```
var newFrame: NSRect
if sender.selectedSegment == 0 {      //leftToolbar button clicked
    if leftToolbar.frame.width > 0 {       //leftToolbar is closed
        newFrame = self.leftToolbar.frame
        newFrame.size.width = 0
        self.leftToolbar.setFrame(newFrame, display: true, animate: true)
    } else {
        newFrame = self.leftToolbar.frame
        newFrame.size.width = self.sidebarsWidth
        self.leftToolbar.setFrame(newFrame, display: true, animate: true)
    }
}
```

code 2: the NSNotification of the resizing.

```
func windowResized(notification: NSNotification) {
    var win = notification.object as NSWindow
    // (...)    code from main window resizing
    if (win.isEqual(self.leftToolbar)) {    // Resizing or Animation of the left sidebar
        leftTable!.view.frame = (self.leftToolbar.contentView as NSView).frame
        var newFrame = self.mainContent.frame
        if self.leftToolbar.frame.width > 0 {     // if the sidebar is open
            newFrame.origin.x = self.mainWin.frame.origin.x+self.leftToolbar.frame.width+10.0
            newFrame.origin.y = self.mainWin.frame.origin.y+5.0
            if self.rightToolbar.frame.width > 0 {      // if right sidebar is open
                newFrame.size.width = self.mainWin.frame.width-10.0-10.0-self.leftToolbar.frame.width-self.rightToolbar.frame.width
            } else {
                newFrame.size.width = self.mainWin.frame.width-10.0-5.0-self.leftToolbar.frame.width-self.rightToolbar.frame.width
            }
        } else {      // sidebar is now closed
            newFrame.origin.x = self.mainWin.frame.origin.x+self.leftToolbar.frame.width+5.0
            newFrame.origin.y = self.mainWin.frame.origin.y+5.0
            if self.rightToolbar.frame.width > 0 {      // if right sidebar is open
                newFrame.size.width = self.mainWin.frame.width-5.0-10.0-self.leftToolbar.frame.width-self.rightToolbar.frame.width
            } else {
                newFrame.size.width = self.mainWin.frame.width-5.0-5.0-self.leftToolbar.frame.width-self.rightToolbar.frame.width
            }
        }
        self.mainContent.setFrame(newFrame, display: true)      // set the mid (child) window to occupy the space inherited from the left sidebar
    }
    // (...)   Code from right sidebar resizing
}
```

NOTE1: This is my code, developed by me and not copied from somewhere.

NOTE2: You can consider the resizing going ok, as they are tested and working. They just have a flicker when with content as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Got to solve the problem. The child windows when set to frame with 0 width, get memory dump or something like that, so, setting the child windows to 1 width and "hiding" them was the correct solution here.